# Can light photons have shape of a leaf?

Tags: visible-light, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

Can light photons be in the shape of a leaf ,so that when they hit a vertical polariser, they start waving in the vertical direction and vice versa .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Like a leaf is better said as, a shape in a plane.  Yes light is planar, see Maxwell.  About 50% of photons pass, it is probability, the better aligned the better the chance. Many polarizers emit at 90 deg to the acceptance angle, i.e we call it rotation of the plane!

Answer (score 1):

Photons, like every other elementary particles, have no further structure as long as we know of, they are points. So no, they have no shape. In a polarizer you have an EM wave, which is a collective flux of more than $10^6$ of photons.

Comment: *an EM wave, which is a collective flux of more than $10^6$ of photons* Where did the number $10^6$ come from?

Comment: You are correct in saying that we have no reason to ascribe any shape or  structure to photons, but polarization is not an emergent property of large masses of photons. Each individual photon has polarization. Parallel polarizers will transmit photons that are sent through one-by-one. Crossed polarizers will block the same one-by-one photons. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_polarization

Comment: @Ghoster i read, don't remeber where tho, that you could have sources with a very small number of photons. Take a laser for example, then you have $N_{\gamma} = \frac{ P\Delta t}{\nu_{\gamma}h} $ with $P$ power of the laser and $\Delta t$ the duration of the laser impulse. I set a minimum of $10^6$ to point that even for ultra short and dim pulses, you have a very big number of photons

Comment: @SolomonSlow i never said that polarization is an emergent property, i know that well. I said that the flux seen by a polarizer is. I said that photons are not leafy EM waves, but that EM waves are a collection of shapeless photons.

Comment: That was to point out that a photon doesn't wave in the sense he asked, but that the thing "waving" is the big collection of (polarized) photons